# Debugging Native code in Visual Studio Proff

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2008

The Solution that we work on here includes 1 project in C# and another project in C. Is there any way to debug c code in Visual Studio?

Comment: You may need to install the Visual C++ SKU if not already done.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this for about 20 years.  Of course you need the Visual C++ flavor.

Comment: Thank you Guys...But I want to debug C ..not C++ ..any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if you have the source code, create a project from it, compile as debug (add breakpoints, watches...) and do the debugging.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am able to place the debugger..But the control never falls there.Any idea?? Well, my c project is a DLL Project and doesn't have any entry point.Functions in the c project are called by another application.

Comment: You need to actually have one solution created which contains both projects - the one which calls the library functions and the library itself. Last thing you will have to make sure that the program actually USES the compiled (debug) version of the library. This can be done for example by copying the dll into the same directory as the debug executable. I hope this helps.

Comment: Note: probably you could also attach the debugger to the runinng process and do the debugging this way. But i have little experience with this so i cannot give you more details on how to do this.